# Guardar el entero de una operación en una variable con C

Tags: c

Estoy aprendiendo a usar C, cómo guardo el entero de una operacion en una variable?
intente hacer lo siguiente :

```
k = int((n + b)/d);
```

pero no funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui tienes un ejemplo sencillo para guardar valores enteros en variables, solo declaras el tipo de dato y el nombre de la variable: Ejm: **int variable = 0;**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
 int resultado;      /* defino resultado como un entero */

 resultado = 7 / 3;
 printf("Resultado = %d\n", resultado);  /* muestro el resultado */

 return 0;
}
```

tienes que tener en cuenta que si utilizas un tipo int la operacion se castea, es decir: si divides 7/3= 2.33 pero al declararlo como entero se redondea a 2.

Comment: si gracias, pero por ejemplo cuando quiero guardar la parte entera de dividir 7 entre 3 lo hago así? int k; k = 7/3;

Comment: @LuzBenítez ya edite el ejemplo, espero te sirva, no olvides marcar como respuesta si te ha servido.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo!

Answer (score 1):

Parece que lo que buscas es algo así:

```
int k = (n + b)/d;
```

Aunque si vas a hacer esa operación te recomiendo que la guardes en un `float`

Comment: gracias! me sirvió